# Webscraping a particular element of html

Tags: python, web-scraping

I’m having trouble scraping information from government travel advice websites for a research project I’m doing on Python.

I’ve picked the Turkey page but the logic could extend to any country.

The site is "https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/turkey/safety-and-security"

The code I'm using is:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/turkey/safety-
and-security")
page
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('p')
soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text()
```

At the moment this is extracting all the html of the page. Having inspected the website the information I am interested in is located in:

```
<div class="govuk-govspeak direction-ltr">
  <p>
```

Does anyone know how to amend the code above to only extract that part of the html?

Thanks

Comment: inside `govuk-govspeak direction-ltr` class there are `h and p` tags what exactly you want to extract ?

Comment: On that page I'm looking to extract the h3 id, as below:

<h3 id="local-travel---syrian-border">Local travel - Syrian border</h3>
<h3 id="local-travel--eastern-provinces">Local travel – eastern provinces</h3>
<h3 id="political-situation">Political situation</h3>
<h3 id="crime">Crime</h3>
<h3 id="road-travel">Road travel</h3>

But on other pages from what I can see, I need the whole <p> section:

e.g. 

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/turkey/terrorism

<div class="govuk-govspeak direction-ltr">
  <p>

"Terrorists are very likely to try to carry out attacks....

Comment: check my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in data located inside `govuk-govspeak direction-ltr` class, therefore you can try these steps :

Beautiful Soup supports the most commonly-used `CSS selectors`. Just pass a string into the `.select()` method of a Tag object or the `BeautifulSoup` object itself. For `class` use `.` and for `id` use `#`

```
data = soup.select('.govuk-govspeak.direction-ltr')

# extract h3 tags
h3_tags = data[0].select('h3')
print(h3_tags)
[<h3 id="local-travel---syrian-border">Local travel - Syrian border</h3>, <h3 id="local-travel--eastern-provinces">Local travel – eastern provinces</h3>, <h3 id="political-situation">Political situation</h3>,...]

#extract p tags
p3_tags = data[0].select('p')
[<p>The FCO advise against all travel to within 10 ...]
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome @FJ1993 :) , and if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can find that particular `<div>` and then under that div you can find the `<p>` tags and get the data like this

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/turkey/safety-and-security")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
div=soup.find("div",{"class":"govuk-govspeak direction-ltr"})
data=[]
for i in div.find_all("p"):
    data.append(i.get_text().encode("ascii","ignore"))

data="\n".join(data)
```

now `data` will contain the whole content with paragraphs seperated by `\n`

**Note: The above code will give you only the text content of paragraph heading content will not be included**

if you want both heading with paragraph text then you can extract both `<h3>` and `<p>` like this

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/turkey/safety-and-security")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
div=soup.find("div",{"class":"govuk-govspeak direction-ltr"})
data=[]
for i in div:
    if i.name=="h3":
        data.append(i.get_text().encode("ascii","ignore")+"\n\n")    
    if i.name=="p":
        data.append(i.get_text().encode("ascii","ignore")+"\n")

data="".join(data)
```

Now data will have both headings and paragraphs where headings will be seperated by `\n\n` and paragraphs will be seperated by `\n`

Comment: Thanks. Both of those end with a Syntax error when one adds the final line. The syntax works up to that point, but the code falls when I type the last line. Any ideas?


    data ="".join(data)

       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sorry my mistake now try the code it should work i tested both of them personally. if you try in interactive prompt type line by line if you copy paste, interactive prompt will consider last line as part of for loop so you have to give new line as answered above.